# Logout User from jwt token if user inactive for long period

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I am using react js for my application frontend development and for login my backend server will provide jwt token and with expire time 2 hours for authentication and now my application is working fine and logout after 2 hour complete. But my requirement is to detech user in-activity.And logout when if more then 30 minute in-active. How can i do this i don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would destroy/filter out selecting the JWT key in the back-end for your first 2 hour rule. If you want to regenerate the key on regenerating the JWT you can do it by storing a separate login identifier with it.

Then use the JWT exp value for the 30 minutes rule, and have the JWT regenerated every time it is checked.

If you are not using unique keys the other option would be to regenerate the JWT with 30 min exp, but store the 2 hour rule as a separate value inside the JWT user data and check it in your code.